# Appending text to lines maintaining context

Tags: vimscript, global-command, range

I'm trying to write some script (a function) which I can use to add some additions to a BASH script I'm modifying. This BASH script automates the building of a series of packages. The part of the script I'm wanting to modify is to add an "or die" clause after the three points for which I want some additional info.  Consider this

```bash
die() {
    [[ -z $1 ]] && msg="Unintended early exit" || msg=$1
    echo $msg
    exit 1
}
...

# This is the basic pattern
echo "package"
cd package
mkdir build && cd build
../configure <options>
make -j 8
make install
cd $TOP
```

I want to add onto the `configure`, `build` and `install` lines with the `die()` function to help in seeing when problems are encountered:

```bash
# This is the basic pattern
echo "package"
cd package
mkdir build && cd build
../configure <options> || die "package failed to configure"
make -j 8 || die "package failed to build"
make install || die "package failed to install"
cd $TOP
```

Since each "block" of the script *starts* with the `echo` command, I'm basically wanting to do this `g/^echo/call AddDie()`.

So, I'm trying to write a function named `AddDie()` which basically does

- copy `package` into the `0` register
- "for this block" append: die || "ph failed to ..."
- "for this block" change each instance of "ph" to "package"

For this I've tried various things like this

```
function! AddDie()
    exec 'norm f"lyt"'
    exec 'norm }me``'
    .,'eg/configure/exec 'norm A || die "ph failed to configure"'
    .,'eg/make -j/exec 'norm A || die "ph failed to build"'
    .,'eg/install/exec 'norm A || die "ph failed to install"'
    .,'es/ph/\<C-R>0\<CR>
endfunction
```

Which results in all kinds of "nope" from vim.  Most of the errors are "cannot do global recursive with a range."  Lots of Googling returns hits for global recursive stuff but not really anything about why this range isn't possible.  Looking through some hits from this site I think I've learned I have to use the `exec ...` for everything not just what the `:g` command finds within the range, but I don't understand why.  Isn't vimscript supposed to work with ex commands and these commands take ranges right?

I'd appreciate any insights and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question because I could not understand why the `global` command was continually throwing errors about "recursive calls to global cannot use ranges."  After digging with Google, and reflecting on what I'm writing, I realized the source of the error.  I'm calling a function from the use of `:g` which is calling `:g` within the function.  This is the source of the recursion.  After discovering this, I turned my attention to using vim functions for what I want instead of trying to script a whole bunch of ex commands together.  The end result is definitely less cryptic and does what I need it to do.

The end result function is:

```
function! AddDie() range
    exec 'norm f"lyt"'
    let pkg_name = getreg(0)
    let target_line = search('../configure', "n", a:lastline)
    let to_change = getline(target_line, a:lastline)
    call setline(target_line, to_change[0] . ' || die "' . pkg_name . ' failed to configure"')

    let target_line = search('make -j', "n", a:lastline)
    let to_change = getline(target_line, a:lastline)
    call setline(target_line, to_change[0] . ' || die "' . pkg_name . ' failed to build"')

    let target_line = search('install', "n", a:lastline)
    let to_change = getline(target_line, a:lastline)
    call setline(target_line, to_change[0] . ' || die "' . pkg_name . ' failed to install"')

endfunction
```

This does what I wanted.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need `:execute 'normal! …'` unless there's some weird characters or you're building the command programatically. My version of your first command would either be `:normal! 0yi"` or `:let pkg_name = matchstr(getline('.'), '"\zs.*\ze"')` or `:let line = getline('.')` and `:let pkg_name = line[stridx(line, '"')+1:strridx(line, '"')]` or something like that. But the whole thing feels like a macro: `0yi"/configure<cr>A || die "<c-r>0 failed to configure<esc>/make -j<cr>A || die "<c-r>0 failed to build"<esc>/install<cr>A || die "<c-r>0 failed to install`.

Comment: In ex, probably `:normal! yi"` `:/configure/normal! A || "die "…`, etc. But anyway, interesting post :) Note that `:help E147`, which the error thrown, gives more info.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thank you! I didn't not think to use the `i` motion command in that way.  That is better.

Comment: Yet another alternative: replace the `:global` calls inside the function with `:substitute` calls: e.g. `.,'es/configure.*/& || die "ph failed to configure"`

Comment: @Andrew, is your solution solving your problem? If so maybe could you validate your answer using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt it did do what I needed and I have clicked the check

Comment: Thanks Andrew :-)